# How to find sum of numbers from a file using a while loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes a file name as an argument, and returns the sum of the numbers in the file. Here is what I have done so far:

```
def sum_digits (filename):
    """
    >>> sum_digits("digits.txt")
    434
    """
    myfile = open(filename, "r")
    newfile = myfile.read()
    sum = 0
    while newfile.isdigit():
        sum += newfile%10
        newfile = newfile/10
    return sum

if __name__=="__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

But this code is not working. I dont know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `digits.txt` look like? Is it a series of numbers with one number per line?

Comment: Its just a line of numbers: 1 23 10 99 125 35 87 54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your text to get a list of numbers, then iterate over that adding them up:

```
nums = newfile.split()
for num in nums:
    sum += int(num)
```

Comment: I get this error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: Oops, forgot the `int`.

Comment: sum( int(x) for x in newfile.split())